# What is the difference in meaning between "tipped the scales for me" and "tipped the scales with me"?

Tags: meaning

I saw the following sentences on the internet. In some sentences, "tipped the scales for" is used, and in other sentences, "tipped the scales with" is used. What semantic difference is there? If there is a difference, I would appreciate it if you could explain it with a specific examples.

> Both travel destinations are good, but beautiful scenery of the sea
> tipped the scales ***for*** me.
>
> Your positive attitude tipped the scales ***with*** interviewers.

What is the  exact difference in meaning between "beautiful scenery of the sea tipped the scales **for** me" and "beautiful scenery of the sea tipped the scales **with** me"?

Comment: The choice of preposition makes *no difference whatsoever* in your cited context - apart from the possibility that people might question your command of English if you use ***with*** because it's *so* much less common. But note that there's nothing actually "wrong" with even this example: [*Whether the first presidential debate tipped the scales **to** Kennedy or not, the scales were tipped in his favor during the campaign.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tipped+the+scales+to+Kennedy%22)

Comment: [If you look at Google Ngrams, only "tipped the scales **for** me" seems to be common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tipped+the+scales+*+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3); "with" is apparently so uncommon it doesn't even show up.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much difference in meaning.

> From my point of view, the beautiful scenery was what tipped the scales (made me prefer this destination to another which was nearly as good).
>
> Your positive attitude tipped the scales as far as the interviewers were concerned.